# Setting range of a colormap in Matplotlib

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, range

I'm using matplotlib to plot a simple graph:

```
cm=plt.get_cmap('Blues')

nx.draw_circular(G,
        node_color='White',
        edge_color=range(G.number_of_edges()),
        edge_cmap=cm,
        node_size=900,
        width=4
        )
```

I want to set a range on the colormap 'Blues' in such a way to delete the white color which is not visible in the draw.

Please help!

Sorry for bad english.

Comment: Where is draw_circular coming from ? I do not see it in matplotlib. What happens with     node_color='Blue'    ?

Comment: @Louis, I think it is from networkx module.

Answer (score 2):

The range (or [normilization](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/colors_api.html#module-matplotlib.colors)) is not really a feature of the colormap, but is often implemented as a feature in the functions that plot using colormaps.  For example, [`imshow` uses `vmin` and `vmax`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow), so you might try using these as keywords with `draw_circular` (I can't find the documentation), or maybe `norm`.

Other than this, you can make your own colormap with exact color arrangement that you want.  There are plenty of examples on how to make custom colormaps, and a few different approaches available.  Here ([a](http://assorted-experience.blogspot.com/2007/07/custom-colormaps.html), [b](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/ColormapTransformations), [c](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/api/colorbar_only.html), [d](http://sites.google.com/site/theodoregoetz/notes/matplotlib_colormapadjust)) are a few examples that might be useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem trying to plot data with different colormaps:

[image: Blues vs Reds]

It's hard to which of the whitish dots belong to which distribution. I solved this problem by chopping off the whiter parts of the colormap spectrum:

[image: Blues vs Reds with white removed]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap


def chop_cmap_frac(cmap: LinearSegmentedColormap, frac: float) -> LinearSegmentedColormap:
    """Chops off the beginning `frac` fraction of a colormap."""
    cmap_as_array = cmap(np.arange(256))
    cmap_as_array = cmap_as_array[int(frac * len(cmap_as_array)):]
    return LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(cmap.name + f"_frac{frac}", cmap_as_array)


cmap1 = plt.get_cmap('Reds')
cmap2 = plt.get_cmap('Blues')

cmap1 = chop_cmap_frac(cmap1, 0.4)
cmap2 = chop_cmap_frac(cmap2, 0.4)
np.random.seed(42)
n = 50
xs = np.random.normal(size=n)
ys = np.random.normal(size=n)
vals = np.random.uniform(size=n)

plt.scatter(xs, ys, c=vals, cmap=cmap1)
plt.scatter(ys, xs, c=vals, cmap=cmap2)
plt.gca().set_facecolor('black')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```